Kernel of the canonical map on tensor and wedge products
This question comes from page. 76 of the book Fulton, William; Harris, Joe, Representation theory. A first course, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 129. New York etc.: Springer-Verlag,. xv, 551 p., 144 ill. (1991). ZBL0744.22001.
Let $ V $ be a finite vector space on $\mathbb{C}$, and consider the map
$$
f: \Lambda^2 V \otimes V \to \Lambda^3 V
$$
defined by
$$
f((v_1 \wedge v_2) \otimes v_3) = v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge v_3.
$$
I am trying to understand the structure of $\ker(f)$ and show that it can be described by the following span:
$$
\ker(f) = \operatorname{span}\{(v_1 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_2 + (v_2 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_1 : v_1, v_2, v_3 \in V\}.
$$
In other words, I want to show that if $ X = (v_1 \wedge v_2) \otimes v_3 \in \ker(f) $, then it can be written as
$$
X = (v_1 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_2 + (v_2 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_1.
$$
How can I rigorously show that any element $ (v_1 \wedge v_2) \otimes v_3 \in \ker(f) $ can be written as $ (v_1 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_2 + (v_2 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_1 $?
What I have so far:

Since $ X \in \ker(f) $, we know that
$$
   f((v_1 \wedge v_2) \otimes v_3) = v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge v_3 = 0.
   $$
This implies that the vectors $ v_1 $, $ v_2 $, and $ v_3 $ are linearly dependent and $(v_1\wedge v_2)\otimes v_3=v_3 \otimes (v_1 \wedge v_2)$.

There I stuck: substituting this into $ X = (v_1 \wedge v_2) \otimes v_3 =v_3 \otimes (v_1 \wedge v_2)$ doesn't lead to something. However, I am struggling to see how this approach leads to the expression $ (v_1 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_2 + (v_2 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_1 $.


A detailed explanation of the steps involved would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Caution! Not every element of the tensor product is a pure tensor, similarly for the exterior power. This is why your approach isn't working. Also, the whole classical idea of working with elements is not working. You have to think about morphisms and the universal properties involved here. Verify that $\Lambda^3 V$ satisfies the same universal property as $(\Lambda^2 V \otimes V)/U$ for the subspace $U$ defined here. It can also be proven more conceptually by using the right exactness of the tensor product. I will leave these hints here and wait for your progress before posting a full answer.

Just to recap: universal property of tensor product is that it classifies multilinear maps. Universal property of exterior power: alternating multilinear maps. Quotient space: linear maps that vanish on the subspace.

First of all, thank you very much for your suggestions!
Let me fully understand your hints. We have to prove that for any vector space $W$ and for any alternating map $\beta: V \times V \times V \rightarrow W$, there exists a unique linear map $g: (\Lambda^2 V \otimes V)/U \to W$ such that $g((v_1 \wedge v_2) \otimes v_3 + U) = \beta(v_1, v_2, v_3)$, where $U = \operatorname{span}{(v_1 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_2 + (v_2 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_1 : v_1, v_2, v_3 \in V}$. Is that correct?

Here, the book tells me that the kernel is $U = \operatorname{span}{(v_1 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_2 + (v_2 \wedge v_3) \otimes v_1 : v_1, v_2, v_3 \in V}$. However, if I didn't have the text, how could I understand the generators of the kernel of that map? That is, let ${e_1, \dots, e_n}$ be a basis for $V$, and let $v \in \ker(f)$. So, $\sum_{i,j,k} a_{ijk}(e_i \wedge e_j \wedge e_k) = 0$ (where $a_{ijk} \in \mathbb{C}$). From this, how can one understand that the generators of $U$ have that form as I can't manipulation those elements anymore??? This looks so strange to me.

For the 1st comment: Yes  but you also need to prove that $(v_1,v_2,v_3) \mapsto (v_1 \wedge v_2) \otimes v_3 \bmod U$ is alternating, the universal example. For the 2nd comment: It is wrong to use bases here. I will write an answer.

This question has nothing to do with vector spaces, finite-dimensionality, or the field of complex numbers. It is recommended to throw all these useless assumptions away because they invite us to use stuff which is not relevant and in fact overcomplicates the proof (such as, choosing a basis, and trying lengthy computations). So let us work with arbitrary modules instead. If you are more familiar with vector spaces, just replace "module" with "vector space" below.
Also, as mentioned in the comments already, one has to be very careful when dealing with tensor products and exterior powers, since here the usual approach of working with elements is not the correct one. In particular not every element of a tensor product is a pure tensor, it is just a sum of pure tensors, but even then it is hard to decide when two such sums are equal. But luckily, we don't need to deal with this, and instead use the universal properties of tensor products and exterior powers, which can (should) also be regarded as their definition.
Let $M$ be some $R$-module, where $R$ is a commutative ring. Recall that $\Lambda^n(M)$ is defined as an $R$-module with a universal alternating multilinear map $\wedge : M^n \to \Lambda^n(M)$. Every alternating map is also antisymmetric, and the converse holds when $2 \in R^{\times}$ (for example, when working with a field of characteristic $\neq 2$). For the purpose of this question, we need to make this assumption. (Alternatively, we may use the "antisymmetric power" instead of the "exterior power", this will work with every commutative ring.)
Notice that already the definition of $f : \Lambda^2(M) \otimes M \to \Lambda^3(M)$ via
$$f((x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3) := x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_3$$
requires an explanation because of the mentioned reasons: not every element of $\Lambda^2(M) \otimes M$ will be of the form $(x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3$, and even those which can be, cannot be represented uniquely in this form. We need to invoke the universal properties of tensor product and exterior power to construct $f$. It will be automatically linear, but the not-so-obvious part is to show that $f$ is "well-defined".
First of all, it is a general fact linear maps
$$f: N \otimes M \to K$$
correspond to linear maps
$$f' : M \to \mathrm{Hom}(N,K)$$
via
$$f(n \otimes m) = f'(m)(n),$$
where $\mathrm{Hom}(N,K)$ is the module of linear maps from $N$ to $K$. This is a reformulation of the universal property of the tensor product (since $f'$ is the same as a bilinear map). Therefore, to construct $f$, it will be sufficient to construct a linear map
$$f' : M \to \mathrm{Hom}(\Lambda^2(M),\Lambda^3(M)).$$
This should be easy since the universal property of $\Lambda^2(M)$ allows us to construct linear maps on it.
So let $x_3 \in M$. Consider the map $M^2 \to \Lambda^3(M)$, $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_3$. It is easy to verify that it is multilinear and antisymmetric, using the corresponding property of $\wedge : M^3 \to \Lambda^3(M)$. Hence, there is a unique linear map $\Lambda^2(M) \to \Lambda^3(M)$ that maps $x_1 \wedge x_2$ to $x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_3$. Again notice that this is a linear extension, so for example $a \wedge b + c \wedge d$ is mapped to $a \wedge b \wedge x_3 + c \wedge d \wedge x_3$.
This linear map $\Lambda^2(M) \to \Lambda^3(M)$ is our $f'(x_3)$. It is easy to check that $f'(x_3 + y_3) = f'(x_3) + f'(y_3)$ and $f'(r x_3) = r f'(x_3)$, just by going through the definition of $f'$. Therefore, $f' : M \to \mathrm{Hom}(\Lambda^2(M),\Lambda^3(M))$ is indeed linear. Therefore, there is a unique linear map $f : \Lambda^2(M) \otimes M \to \Lambda^3(M)$ characterized by
$$f((x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3) = f'(x_3)(x_1 \wedge x_3) = x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_3.$$
Remember that our goal is to prove that the kernel of $f$ is equal to some submodule $U$ of $\Lambda^2(M) \otimes M$. Instead of proving that directly with elements (that will probably not work, and does not fit the spirit of universal objects), we need to construct an isomorphism of modules between $(\Lambda^2(M) \otimes M)/U$ and $\Lambda^3(M)$. Namely, this is equivalent to a surjective homomorphism $\Lambda^2(M) \otimes M \to \Lambda^3(M)$ with kernel $U$, and this homomorphism will coincide with $f$, so that indeed $\ker(f)=U$.
We define $U \subseteq \Lambda^2(M) \otimes M$ to be the submodule generated by elements of the form
$$(x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3 + (x_3 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_1.$$
So the middle element stays, the two outer ones get exchanged. Notice that $f$ vanishes on such elements:
$$f(((x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3 + (x_3 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_1) = x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_3 + x_3 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_1 = 0,$$
using that $\wedge$ is antisymmetric. Hence, by the universal property of the quotient module (aka "fundamental theorem on homomorphisms") there is a unique linear map
$$\overline{f} : (\Lambda^2(M) \otimes M)/U \to \Lambda^3(M),\quad [(x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3] \mapsto x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_3.$$
Here I denote by $[\dotsc]$ the projection modulo the submodule $U$, i.e. $[m] = m + U$ if you are using cosets (which you don't have to).
It is immediately clear that $\overline{f}$ is surjective, and our goal is to prove that $\overline{f}$ is an isomorphism (this is equivalent to $\ker(f) = U$). To achieve this, we will construct a homomorphism $g$ in the other direction and verify that it is inverse to $\overline{f}$. Actually, checking $g \circ \overline{f} = \mathrm{id}$ will be enough since $\overline{f}$ is surjective.
To construct $g : \Lambda^3(M) \to (\Lambda^2(M) \otimes M)/U$, we must use the universal property of $\Lambda^3(M)$. For this, consider the following map:
$$\tau : M^3 \to (\Lambda^2(M) \otimes M)/U,\quad (x_1,x_2,x_3) \mapsto [(x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3].$$
It is immediate that $\tau$ is multilinear. It is not so obvious that $\tau$ is antisymmetric, this is what we need to check, and here the definition of $U$ will also come into play. We have to check three things.

$\tau(x_1,x_2,x_3) = - \tau(x_2,x_1,x_3)$. This follows from $x_1 \wedge x_2 = - (x_2 \wedge x_1)$.
$\tau(x_1,x_2,x_3) = - \tau(x_3,x_2,x_1)$. That is, $[(x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3] = -[(x_3 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_1]$. This is equivalent to $[(x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3 +  (x_3 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_1] = 0$, which is immediate from the definition of $U$.
$\tau(x_1,x_2,x_3) = - \tau(x_1,x_3,x_2)$. This is a formal consequence of 1. and 2.

Hence, there is a unique linear map characterized by
$$g : \Lambda^3(M) \to (\Lambda^2(M) \otimes M)/U, \quad g(x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_3) = \tau(x_1,x_2,x_3) = [(x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3].$$
It remains to check that $g \circ \overline{f} = \mathrm{id}$. Since $\Lambda^2(M) \otimes M$ is generated by "pure" elements of the form $(x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3$, it suffices to check the equation $g(\overline{f}((x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3)) = (x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3$, which is an immediate consequence of the definitions of $\overline{f}$ and $g$.
Let me say that most of this answer is not really about this specific example with the exterior power, but it attempts to teach more generally how to attack these kind of problems (hence, the length). And also it is worthwile mentioning that this is still not the most elegant approach. Using concepts from category theory (or homological algebra, if you want) you can basically write down the whole proof in two lines, but I will not digress any further.
PS.
Since it was asked in the comments, here a short remark how to come up with the kernel $U$. It is closely connected to the proof above. Assume we have already constructed $f$ as above. It is clear that $f$ is surjective, but it cannot be injective since the elements $x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_3$ have more relations than the elements $(x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3$. Namely, even though the $(x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3$ are antisymmetric in $x_1,x_2$, they are not necessarily antisymmetric in $x_1,x_3$. That is, $(x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3$ is not the same as $- (x_3 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_1$, even though of course $x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_3$ is the same as $- x_3 \wedge x_2 \wedge x_1$. We find $f((x_1 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_3) = - f((x_3 \wedge x_2) \otimes x_1)$. This shows (again) that the submodule $U$ defined above lies in the kernel of $f$.

typo at the end of the sentence "Again notice that this is a linear extension..."

That's a great explanation, thank you very much!
Just the last thing, the book told me that the kernel is generated by ${(v_1\wedge v_3)\otimes v_2+(v_2\wedge v_3)\otimes v_1:v_1,v_2,v_3\in V}$ as $\mathbb{C}$-vector space. However, if I didn't have the text, how could I understand the generators of the kernel of that map, by myself for example?

@Hola Please see the section I've added in the end.
